# What had missed out in declare scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have error messages for this part of coding below:

```
/*Months need to be refreshed*/
DECLARE @Month NVARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @Row NVARCHAR(1)

SELECT @MONTH=MONTH, @YEAR=YEAR
FROM calendar

select month, year, 1 as row into #period from calendar;

insert into #period (month, year, row)
values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-1 END,CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,2)

insert into #period (month, year, row)
values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-2 END,CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,3)

/*Refresh latest month*/
DECLARE @Updstm NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Month1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Month2 VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Year1 NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @ROW1 VARCHAR(25) 
DECLARE @MAX_ROW1 VARCHAR(25)  

SET @MAX_ROW1=(SELECT MAX([ROW]) FROM #period)
SET @ROW1=1 WHILE @ROW1<=@MAX_ROW1

BEGIN
SELECT @Month1 = N'SELECT @SVMonth2 = SVMonth FROM #period WHERE [ROW]='+@ROW1
EXEC sp_executesql @Month1, N'@Month2 VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @Month2 OUTPUT

SET @Updstm= ''
SET @Updstm= '
INSERT INTO #remove
select memberid, '+@Month1+' as month
from member'+@Month1+' where memberid in ("A2019358219",
"A3012467679",
"A5513538670")';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Updstm

SET @ROW1=@ROW1+1

END
```

Error messages were:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Month2".

What have I missed?

Calendar Sample Data:

```
Month | Year
9     | 2019
```

Member Sample Data:

```
MemberId    | Sales  | Qty
A2019358219 | 166703 | 90
A3012467679 | 170489 | 34
A5513538670 | 38689  | 18
```

Comment: what you try to do with this query may i know ?? is a stored procedure

Comment: @DaleBurrell  I have added in the full script

Comment: the script is still not a "full script" - it should include all `#temp` table `CREATE` necessary to actually execute it. We should be able to open a new window in SSMS. Execute the script in it and see the error you are asking about

Comment: @user5193498 you are wasting a lot of peoples time by not having a [mre] - people are trying to solve the problem for you, but the problem doesn't exist in the code posted.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, I'm really sorry for that. I have attached the full code

Comment: May I know how can i attach the sample data here?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, sorry, #curr_period is actually #period. I have edited.

Comment: OK, I have posted an answer which hopefully resolves the issue for you. In future please ensure any questions you ask are fully setup and reproducible, as my answer is, in order for people to be able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Your END is missing for your WHILE loop:

```
DECLARE @Updstm NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Month1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Month2 VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Year1 NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @ROW1 VARCHAR(25) 
DECLARE @MAX_ROW1 VARCHAR(25)  

SET @MAX_ROW1=(SELECT MAX([ROW]) FROM #curr_period)
SET @ROW1=1 WHILE @ROW1<=@MAX_ROW1


BEGIN
    SELECT @Month1 = N'SELECT @Month2 = Month FROM #curr_period WHERE [ROW]=' + @ROW1
    EXEC sp_executesql @Month1, N'@Month2 VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @Month2 OUTPUT
END
```

Comment: That might be an error, but its not the one being asked about.

Answer (score 1):

OK, follows is some semi-working code i.e. is runs, but whether it does what you require I don't know.

This should be a template for any further SQL Questions you post, where you setup the data, attempt the query and then post the expected results. 90% of the time you will solve the problem yourself by doing this. And for the last 10% you've made it really easy for anyone trying to assist to setup and reproduce the problem.

I have commented on every issue I had to resolve in order to get this code to work.

```
/* FIRST SETUP TEST DATA TO DEMONSTRATE THE ISSUE*/
create table #remove (id varchar(12), month int)
create table #member1 (memberid varchar(12))
create table #member12 (memberid varchar(12))
create table #calendar (year int, month int)

/* Add enough sample data here to demonstrate the issue */
insert into #calendar (month, year) select 1, 2019;
insert into #member1 (memberid) select 'A5513538670';
insert into #member12 (memberid) select 'A5513538670';

/* NOW FOR THE CODE WHICH DOESN"T YET WORK */

/*Months need to be refreshed*/
DECLARE @Month NVARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @Year NVARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @Row NVARCHAR(1);

SELECT @MONTH=1, @YEAR=2019
FROM #calendar; -- calendar

-- Missing column svmonth as required in the dynamic SQL
--select month, year, 1 as row into #period from (select 1 month, 2019 year) x;
select month, month svmonth, year, 1 as row into #period from #calendar;

-- Missing column svmonth as required in the dynamic SQL
--insert into #period (month, year, row)
--  values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-1 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,2)
--insert into #period (month, year, row)
--  values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-2 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,3)
insert into #period (month, svmonth, year, row)
  values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-1 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-1 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=1 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,2)
-- Can't use with this data because it causes a month of -1 which breaks the last dynamic code
--insert into #period (month, svmonth, year, row)
--  values (CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-2 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN 12 ELSE @MONTH-2 END, CASE WHEN @MONTH=2 THEN @YEAR-1 ELSE @YEAR END,3)

/* Refresh latest month */
DECLARE @Updstm NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Month1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Month2 VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @Year1 NVARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @ROW1 VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE @MAX_ROW1 VARCHAR(25);
-- Missing variable
DECLARE @SVMonth2 VARCHAR(2);

SET @MAX_ROW1 = (SELECT MAX([ROW]) FROM #period);
SET @ROW1 = 1;

WHILE @ROW1<=@MAX_ROW1 BEGIN
  SELECT @Month1 = N'SELECT @SVMonth2 = SVMonth FROM #period WHERE [ROW] = ' + @ROW1;

  -- select the dynamic SQL in order to work out what is wrong with it.
  -- select @Month1;

  -- Passed in @Month2 but internally used @SVMonth2
  --EXEC sp_executesql @Month1, N'@Month2 VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @Month2 OUTPUT;
  EXEC sp_executesql @Month1, N'@SVMonth2 VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @SVMonth2 OUTPUT;

  SET @Updstm= '';
  -- Used @Month1 instead of @SVMonth2, and doubled quoted ID's instead of using 2 single quotes
  --SET @Updstm= '
  --INSERT INTO #remove (id, month)
  --  select memberid, ' + @SVMonth2 + ' as month
  --  from #member' + @SVMonth2 + ' where memberid in ("A2019358219",
  --  "A3012467679",
  --  "A5513538670")';
  SET @Updstm= '
  INSERT INTO #remove (id, month)
    select memberid, ' + @SVMonth2 + ' as month
    from #member' + @SVMonth2 + ' where memberid in (''A2019358219'',
    ''A3012467679'',
    ''A5513538670'')';

  -- select the dynamic SQL in order to work out what is wrong with it.
  --select @Updstm;

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Updstm;

  SET @ROW1=@ROW1+1;

END

/* CLEAN UP */

drop table #calendar;
drop table #period;
drop table #remove;
drop table #member1;
drop table #member12;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Month1, N'@Month2 VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT', @SomeProcVar = @Month2 OUTPUT
```

See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/262499/how-to-specify-output-parameters-when-you-use-the-sp-executesql-stored)

Comment: should be `@Month2 = @SomeProcVar OUTPUT`